# return object in switch statement got unexpected token ,

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with my switch statement below? Error at ... `key: data}`??

```
__normalizer = (data) => {
    if(data){
        switch(data) {
            case 'promo':
                {name: 'Promotion', key: data}
            break

            default:
                data
        }

    }

    return data
}
```

Comment: perhaps you meant `return {name: 'Promotion', key: data}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Switch/case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) does not assign or return anything. Your intention is to create and return an object, but you don't assign or return it. As noted in [torazaburo comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879060/return-object-in-switch-statement-got-unexpected-token/44879081?noredirect=1#comment76741104_44879081) What you actually have is a [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with a syntax error.

You need to return the object, or assign it to a variable. In addition, you also need to return the data, if it falls through the `promo` case.

```
__normalizer = (data) => {
    if(data){
        switch(data) {
            case 'promo':
                return { name: 'Promotion', key: data };
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

You can simplify your code easily, by removing the switch/case:

```
__normalizer = (data) => {
  if (data === 'promo') {
    return { name: 'Promotion', key: data };
  }

  return data;
}
```

Comment: You have to return whatever value you want to get from the function, or assign it to a variable, and return it afterwards.

Comment: @OriDrori .your switch case not closing properly

Comment: @OriDrori .your switch case not have break

Comment: @prasad - it does not need break. I'm returning instead.

Comment: No, in his code he is not creating an object; he is starting a code block with the `{`, and then things go downhill from there.

Comment: @torazaburo - I've meant "try to create", but you're right. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add "return " before "{name: 'Promotion', key: data}" and "data".

Answer (score -1):

You need return in end of the `if`.And assign the `data` with each case result.

```js
__normalizer = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      switch (data) {
        case 'promo':
          data = {
            name: 'Promotion',
            key: data
          };
          break;
        default:
          data = data
      }
      return data
    }
    }
    console.log(__normalizer('promo'))
```